# Setting a cookie to close div

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Recently we added a bar to warn users our site users cookies, with an accept button that is meant to close and set a cookie so it would not show for some time, however in practice this doesn't actually work.

I was wondering if someone could let me know what I might have got wrong with this following code (The Accept button is the action button for the cookie.):

```
<div class="pea_cook_wrapper pea_cook_bottomright">
        <p>TEXT <a href="#" id="fom">more information</a> <button id="pea_cook_btn" class="pea_cook_btn" href="#">Accept</button></p>
    </div><div class="pea_cook_more_info_popover">
        <div class="pea_cook_more_info_popover_inner">
         <p>TEXT</a>
            <p><a href="#" id="pea_close">Close</a></p>
        </div>
    </div><script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#fom").click(function() {
              $(".pea_cook_more_info_popover").fadeIn("slow");
              $(".pea_cook_wrapper").fadeOut("fast");
            });
            $("#pea_close").click(function() {
              $(".pea_cook_wrapper").fadeIn("fast");
              $(".pea_cook_more_info_popover").fadeOut("slow");
            });
            $('#pea_cook_btn').click(function() {
                var today = new Date();
                var expire = new Date();
                var expireTimer = 7776000;
                document.cookie = "peadigCookie=set;";
            $(".pea_cook_wrapper").fadeOut("fast");
            });
        }); </script>
```

Thanks,

NG

Comment: It does not work how? Is the cookie created? Do you have JS errors when clicking the button? Also, where is your code that checks whether the cookie exists or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can download the jquery [cookie plugin](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) , it will help you to simplify the usage, and you can read the values on your code and change the layouts with your logic.

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");//sets cookie
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 }); //sets cookiewith expiry time
$.cookie("example") //gets cookie
$.cookie("example", null); //deletesthe cookie
```